# Assign value to a column based on a string-based hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to create a new column in a Pandas DataFrame where two columns are compared, and based on a pre-defined hierarchy a third column is populated after the comparison of the two columns. The new column will take the higher of the two based on the hierarchy. The hierarchy is as follows from highest to lowest:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
```

The DataFrame `df` is seen below.

```
sales_code   price_bucket_a   price_bucket_b
101          A1               A2
102          A3               A4
202          A2               A3
201          A4               A5
301          A2               A2 
302          A5               A1
```

The desired output I am attempting to achieve is seen below.

```
sales_code   price_bucket_a   price_bucket_b   price_bucket_hier
101          A1               A2               A1
102          A3               A4               A3
202          A2               A3               A2
201          A4               A5               A4
301          A2               A2               A2
302          A5               A1               A1
```

The hierarchy and DataFrame in question is just a snippet of the overall totals.

Any assistance that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we need convert to category then we can do `min` or `max` to get the right answer

```
cat=['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']
df[['price_bucket_a','price_bucket_b']].apply(lambda x : pd.Categorical(x, categories=cat,ordered=True )).min(axis=1)
0    A1
1    A3
2    A2
3    A4
4    A2
dtype: object
```

Comment: `pd.Categorical` makes total sense here :) +1

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach IIUC:

```
ix = df.filter(like='price').apply(lambda x: x.str.lstrip('A')).astype(int).idxmin(1)

df['price_bucket_hier'] = df.lookup(range(df.shape[0]), ix)
```

---

```
print(df)

 sales_code price_bucket_a price_bucket_b price_bucket_hier
0         101             A1             A2                A1
1         102             A3             A4                A3
2         202             A2             A3                A2
3         201             A4             A5                A4
4         301             A2             A2                A2
```